# Example of a function whose directional derivatives are always positive

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I need an example of a function  $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow  \Bbb R$ such that it`s directional derivative at the direction of the vector $y$ is such that $\mathbf{D_y}(a)>0$ for a fixed vector $y$ and every $a$ in $\Bbb R^n$

I'm having my doubts with this one since I just proved that there no $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow  \Bbb R$ such that $\mathbf{D_y}(a)>0$ for every  $y$ at a fixed point $a$ in $\Bbb R^n$ by using the property that states that $\mathbf{D_y}(a)=y \nabla f(a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ is fixed, if you have $\nabla f(a)=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ you will have $y\cdot \nabla f(a)=y_1^2+\cdots+y_n^2>0$ (of course, if $y\ne 0$).

This can be easily achieved by taking $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=y_1x_1+\cdots+y_nx_n$. In shorter notation, you can define $f(x)=y\cdot x$.

Comment: Why did you change your answer to this one? It seems to me that your previous solution (which coincidentally I have come up with, too) was correct and more generic.

Comment: Perhaps you noticed that Weierstraß Ramirez edited his question long ago by changing "every fixed vector y" to "a fixed vector y"? I think the value of this question to others is higher if we keep the generic version for arbitrary y which he even flagged as the right answer.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'll roll back.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is as following:

For each $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ find a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the directional derivative $\partial_yf = \mathbf{D}_yf$ is positive.

Please note that for $\|y\|=0$ the directional derivative is always $0$, so I'll exclude that case.

---

I suggest the following approach:

For an arbitrary $y \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$
    f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i x_i
$$

Then we have for $i \in \lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a) = y_i
$$

which means that it is $\nabla f(a) = y$.

This immediately shows that the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $y$ is positive:

$$
    \mathbf{D_y}f(a) = y \cdot \nabla f(a) = y \cdot y = \|y\|^2 > 0
$$

Comment: After answering, I noticed that the question is quite old already... It must have been bumped up because Martin just changed his answer's content radically. Actually it seems his previous, old solution was the same as the one I have just presented.